# How Ingress support JWT Authentication?

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Right now I'm using Ingress-Nginx as the routing service for the traffic externally. However, there are few articles introduce how Ingress plays JWT authentications to protect internal APIs.
Can someone share some information about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per research:

> Different authenticating API calls were has merged in the form of  OAuth 2.0 access tokens.

> These are authentication credentials passed from client to API server, and typically carried as an HTTP header.

JSON Web Token (JWT) as defined by [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) is one of those.

As per docs:

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing
> claims to be transferred between two parties.  The claims in a JWT
> are encoded as a JSON object that is used as the payload of a JSON
> Web Signature (JWS) structure or as the plaintext of a JSON Web
> Encryption (JWE) structure, enabling the claims to be digitally
> signed or integrity protected with a Message Authentication Code
> (MAC) and/or encrypted.

This mechanism can be applied using different ingress controllers like [kubernetes nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/) or [nginxinc ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/configmap-and-annotations.md#auth-and-ssltls).

As per nginx inc docs:

> NGINX auth_request Module is used to Validate Tokens on behalf of backend sercvices.

Requests reach the backend services only when the client has presented a valid token
Existing backend services can be protected with access tokens, without requiring code changes
Only the NGINX instance (not every app) need be registered with the IdP
Behavior is consistent for every error condition, including missing or invalid tokens

> 

So for NGINX acting as a reverse proxy for one or more applications, we can use the auth_request module to trigger an API call to an IdP before proxying a request to the backend.

- In the kubernetes ingress you can find information about [External Authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#external-authentication)

> To use an existing service that provides authentication the Ingress rule can be annotated with **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url** to indicate the URL where the HTTP request should be sent.

Here you can find [working example nginx-subrequest-auth-jwt](https://github.com/carlpett/nginx-subrequest-auth-jwt)

> This project implements a simple JWT validation endpoint meant to be used     with NGINX's subrequest authentication, and specifically work well with the Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller external auth annotations

> It validates a JWT token passed in the Authorization header against a configured public key, and further validates that the JWT contains appropriate claims.

This example is using [PyJwt python library](https://github.com/veonua/jwt_auth) which allows you to encode and decode JSON Web Tokens (JWT)

Additional resource:

- [nginxinc controler](https://www.nginx.com/blog/authenticating-api-clients-jwt-nginx-plus/)
- [kubernetes on github JWT Authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1850)

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this on OpenShift but it's not working, even though I'm using the same annotations that I used previously in k8s and were working. Any ideas?
I did not find ANY online material that discusses this with OpenShift and I'm kind of stuck